# load elements of .mat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-upload, time

I've created and saved a matrix of size 102x20. I would now like to load this .mat file. Therefore, I'm using the command `load('test_file.mat')`.

For the purpose of my analysis, however, I only need the matrix of size 100x20.

I considered using a loop, yet this solution is not very time efficient.

`T=102`;
`N=20`;

```
for t=1:100
   for i=1:N
      load('test_file.mat')
   end
end
```

Is there any fast solution of how to load only the desired part of a matrix?

Comment: why do you want load part of the matrix? As i see, it's a samll matrix and does not need a lot of space to load.

Comment: @OmG the matrix I'm using is way bigger. I just used the small matrix in order to test whether the code works. I Need to load only parts of the matrix as I'm running into problems of *matrix dimension mismatch*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading the mat file over and over again; you should only be loading it once. Let's say your matrix is named `mat`. Then your code should look like:

```
load('test_file.mat');
```

If you want to get a smaller portion of the matrix after it's loaded, you can index it e.g. as follows:

```
smaller_mat = mat(1:100, :);
```

There is not a way to retrieve partial variables from a .mat file, but if you are worried about loading time you can save only part of the variable in the first place. Or you can save it to a file in a different format, e.g. csv, that can be partially loaded.